# CodenameOne "regex.RESyntaxException" while fetching from Cloudinary on iOS

Tags: codenameone

It works perfectly fine in simulator and on Android however fails on iOS.

I don't really have an idea about xcode, so this is the best I can provide:

```
com.codename1.util.regex.RESyntaxException 
at com_codename1_util_regex_RECompiler.syntaxError:231 
at com_codename1_util_regex_RECompiler.compile:1283 
at com_codename1_util_regex_RE.__INIT__:407 
at com_codename1_util_regex_RE.__INIT__:393 
at com_cloudinary_Pattern.compile:22 
at com_cloudinary_Url.__CLINIT__:78 
at com_cloudinary_Cloudinary.url:100
```

The java code (I guess where it breaks):

```
Transformation transformation = new Transformation();        
transformation.width(placeholder.getWidth()).height(placeholder.getHeight()).quality(30).crop("thumb");   
String uRLToFetch = cloudinary.url()
                                        .type("fetch")
                                        .format("jpg") 
                                        .transformation(transformation)
                                        .generate(uRL);
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I asked Steve to take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce this, but I have made a small change so that the regex pattern won't be compiled in the class initializer.  It is possible that there was a race condition there.  Please download the latest cloudinary library here:

https://github.com/shannah/cloudinary-codenameone/releases/tag/1.1.2

Make sure to select "Codename One" -> Refresh CN1 Libs after you add this to your lib directory.